# Can you suggest a font similar to this cursive shoelace style font from the Wale Mixtape

Tags: fonts, font-identification, font-recommendation, calligraphy

I need to find a font similar to this font:

[image]

The font is from a mixtape "[100 Miles & Running](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/100_Miles_%26_Running)" by Wale.

The font does not need to have "shoe lace" at all. Just needs to be cursive and similar looking to the "wale" font. I want free font suggestions and fonts less than $15.

Comment: I'd suggest perusing the script options over at dafont.

Answer (score 1):

A good option is [Sneaker Script](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/flat-it/sneaker-script/)

[image: Sneaker Script Wale]

This font is outside of your price range but I don't remember seeing many fonts below $30.

---

Another kinda close font is [Corner Store](https://typekit.com/fonts/corner-store) from Adobe Type Kit.

[image: corner store wale]

---

This font may be free, [Annabelle](http://fontzone.net/font-details/annabelle)

[image: Annabelle]

These fonts share a free flowing style of writing.

Whenever you see a swirl or long tail at the end of the word it can be an addition made in illustrator.

Check out this tutorial: [CREATE AN EASY HAND LETTERING EFFECT IN ILLUSTRATOR](http://www.graphicmonkee.com/create-an-easy-hand-lettering-effect-in-illustrator) for an example of how to create something like this. The overall idea is to use the pen tool and then use the width tool to widen parts of the path.

Comment: thanks! I like the font, Corner Store. Is it available in the "free" Adobe Type Kit plan? or not. How do I find out?

Comment: @SHE The font is Available for Web according to the site page. You're able to use the font if you have the Adobe Type Kit. I am sure other sites will also sell it if you do not have Adobe Type Kit.

Comment: yes but is it free?

Comment: @SHE If you have Adobe CC subscription, then yes it is free. If you do not have the creative cloud subscription you can pay separably for Adobe Type Kit. I am not sure if the font is available under the FREE version of Adobe Type Kit.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get that exact effect, and ok with spending some time, and familiar with Adobe Illustrator, you might wanna follow the steps [here](http://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/use-pattern-brushes-to-create-a-shoe-lace-text-effect-in-illustrator--vector-22803). Or if you're more of an Adobe Photoshop user, you might wanna follow the steps in the article over [here](http://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-create-realistic-shoelaces-from-scratch-in-photoshop--psd-15848).

Answer (score 0):

There's lot of free fonts on dafont.com BUT be careful, you cannot use the fonts specified "free for personal use" and the demo for any commercial projects. **Read the terms for each font anyway or contact the uploader, it's usually on the font page of each font.**

You'll probably need to modify some elements of the font to get to a result similar to your example, but here are some free fonts to get you started, maybe one of them could be a good match:

**There is this one:**

[image: Dafont Wolf in the city]

http://www.dafont.com/wolf-in-the-city.font?fpp=100&text=Wale

**And this one:**

[image: Dafont Impregnable font]

http://www.dafont.com/impregnable.font?fpp=100&text=Wale

**This:**

[image: Dafont Intrique script font]

http://www.dafont.com/intrique-script.font?fpp=100&text=Wale

**This:**

[image: Dafont Pharmount font]

http://www.dafont.com/pharmount.font?fpp=100&text=Wale

**And:**

[image: Dafont Hemmet font]

http://www.dafont.com/hemmet.font?fpp=100&text=Wale

**Also:**

[image: Dafont Cello script font]

http://www.dafont.com/cellos-script.font?fpp=100&text=Wale

**Another:**

[image: Dafont Big surprise font]

http://www.dafont.com/big-surprise.font?fpp=100&text=Wale

**Finally:**

[image: Dafont 27th RPS font]

http://www.dafont.com/27th-rps.font?fpp=100&text=Wale

You could have a look on the website and see the script section for yourself. You might find something you prefer.